# htaccess RedirectMatch 301 or Redirect 301 or RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to redirect using an htaccess file to do the following.

I want to convert urls like

http://www.site1.com/folder

to

http://www.SITE2.com/index.php?folder

where "folder" can be any alpha-numeric text.

I expect that anything that does not match should be routed to

http://www.SITE2.com/index.php

Basically I want any sub folder to be converted so I can use a $_GET in the index.php file to get the sub folder.

Comment: So you have different domain names?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file of `site1`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?site1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z\d]+)/?$ http://www.SITE2.com/index.php?$1 [L,QSA,NC,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?site1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.SITE2.com/index.php [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Hi anubhava, Thank you so much. I have tested it and it works perfectly. For the benefit of anyone who may be interested, my site1 is http://www.HABF.me and was created to provide suppliers of the main site a short url that they can use to promote their business. By mapping to a GET makes it easy to dynamically display a suppliers site without creating lots of sub-directories.

Comment: I tested this and it works perfectly, exactly what was required, I had not thought of changing the .htaccess in the main domain as well.